# How to prevent UITableView from reloading after a new controller was pushed?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I'm having a store locator (tableview) and a map view. Basically I want to easily go back and forth these two without having to worry about memory. The tableview downloads a chunk of data and parses them into the tableview.

Is there a way I can not load the table view's data again? Something like a modal view controller, but pushing it on instead of presenting it. I don't wish to store the data into NSUserDefaults and checking if that exists because the data is rather large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't explicitly tell a table view to reload the data, it won't.

Either you have some code that explicitly reloads your data, or the map view eats a lot of memory, which triggers a cleanup of your table view controller, essentially removing and later rebuilding your table view.